# Which distribution should be used to calculate prior mean from posterior mean?

Tags: mean, conditional-expectation

I was reading [Pattern recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop.](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) There I found this equation, 2.21, which states how to calculate prior mean as the average of posterior mean.
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta]} =  \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}[\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta|\mathcal{D}]}]$$
where,
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta]} =  \int p(\theta)\theta d\theta$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}[\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta|\mathcal{D}]}]=\int \Big\{ \int \theta p(\theta | \mathcal{D})d\theta\Big\}p(\mathcal{D})d\mathcal{D}$$

But I think the integration formula for $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta]}$ is wrong. It should be,
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}{[\theta]} = \int \int \theta p(\theta,\mathcal{D}) d\theta d\mathcal{D}$$
where $p(\theta,\mathcal{D})$ is the joint probability density of $p$ and $\mathcal{D}$. Otherwise the integration of both sides do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $p(\theta, \mathcal D) = p(\theta \mid \mathcal D) p(\mathcal D)$. Thus your expression is actually the same as the one $\mathbb E_{\mathcal D}[\mathbb E_{\theta}[\theta \mid \mathcal D]]$.

The mean of *any* random variable is $\mathbb E X = \int x p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. The first equation is just that for $\theta$, in terms of the prior $p(\theta)$ which does not depend on the dataset $\mathcal D$.

The relationship is saying that, if you *marginalize* over all possible datasets $\mathcal D$, your belief about the average $\theta$ given a dataset $\mathcal D$ is the same.

Comment: I agree on the first two points. But I can't see how $\int \int \theta p(\theta,\mathcal{D}) d\theta d\mathcal{D}$ can be broken down to $\int \theta p(\theta) d\theta$. Any reference will be helpful.

Comment: @sujoy, use the other direction of conditional probability: $\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal D}$ \begin{align}\iint\! \theta \, p(\theta, \D) \,\ud\theta \,\ud\D
&= \iint\! \theta \, p(\theta) \, p(\D \mid \theta) \,\ud\D \,\ud\theta
\\&= \int\! \theta \, p(\theta) \underbrace{ \int\! p( \D \mid \theta) \ud\D }_{1} \,\ud\theta
\\&= \int\! \theta \, p(\theta) \, \ud\theta .\end{align} This is called [marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) in general.

Comment: $\int p(\mathcal{D}|\theta) d\mathcal{D} = 1 $ implies $p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)=p(\mathcal{D}) = \int p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta$. And this would imply $\mathcal{D}$ and $\theta$ are independently distributed. This is where I was getting stuck from the beginning.

Comment: $\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal D}\int p(\D \mid \theta)\, \mathrm{d}\D = 1$ is true by definition: probability distributions, including that of $\D \mid \theta$, integrate to 1. It is _not_ true that $p(\D \mid \theta) = p(\D)$ – where is that coming from?

Comment: $\int p(\mathcal{D}) d\mathcal{D} = 1 $ is by the definition of probability density, not $\int p(\mathcal{D}|\theta) d\mathcal{D} = 1 $. The later one is about conditional probability.

Comment: @sujoy $p(\D \mid \theta)$ is known as a [conditional probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution). It's still a probability distribution for $\D$.

Comment: how did I miss that? thanks for everything.